# multiple counts and two grouping-by(s)

Tags: sql, database, count, group-by, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write a query that counts the number of submissions for each "Type" and then group it by "Type" and then group it by "FacultyName".
There are 4 types: Books, Book Chapters, Journal Articles and Conferences.
There are 5 faculty names: CLM, EBE, Health Sciences, Humanities and Science.
The "Type" is found in the "Submission" Table and the "FacultyName" is found in the "Faculty" table.

I have attached a screen of a Mock report of what my query should produce: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6p4xvq1u15no6vy/Mock.PNG?dl=0

This is the closest I have got, now I am trying to JOIN the two queries and have it Grouped by Type. All five Faculties will have the 4 Types in common, it is only the count that will be different:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) AS [Number of Submissions]
FROM Submission
GROUP BY Type

SELECT Faculty.FacultyName
FROM Faculty
GROUP BY FacultyName
```

This is the Output: (Sorry i don't have enough points to upload images)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrst3dd9399w8y2/Output.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?. Also `FROM Submission, Faculty` creates a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) (cartesian product) between the two tables. Is that really what you intend to do? If You should rather use an explicit `JOIN` clause to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: using Windows Azure. I am very new to SQL, so I am not entirely certain which clause would be most ideal

Answer (score 0):

Your report shows the number of types per faculty which can be translate in SQL to:

```
SELECT f.faculty,s.type,count(*) as nbr
  FROM Submission s,
       Faculty f
 WHERE --you probably need to join Submission and  Faculty here
       --for example
       --s.id = f.id
GROUP BY f.faculty,s.type
```

Make sure you have the correct join between the two tables (or add relational tables if needed).

Now you will have 3 attributes for your graph, set Faculty and Type as Grouping axis and Nbr as the data set.